# Clearing Data from tables in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I already recorded a macro on this, but it is too bulky and I want to apply this on all tables (except query-tables and pivot table) in all the sheets within the workbook.
I am looking for a macro that wont be too bulky, and easy to execute.

This is a recorded macro of what I intend to do
I don't really know my way around. Can someone help?

```
`Sub ClearData()
'
' ClearData Macro
'

'
    Range("GLORY_INYANG[[DATE]:[CREDIT (Payment)]]").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-201
    Range("A17:E608").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-300
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 299
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 298
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 291
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 244
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 95
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 85
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 75
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 73
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 71
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 70
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 69
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 67
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 66
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 64
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 63
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 60
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 58
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 55
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 46
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 43
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 35
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 8
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 7
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-30
    Rows("25:1411").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-6
    Sheets("ELIZABETH GABRIEL").Select
    Range("ELIZABETH_GABRIEL[[DATE]:[CREDIT (Payment)]]").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=12
    Rows("24:1346").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-1371
    Rows("18:1289").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("D20").Select
    Sheets("GLORY INYANG").Select
    Range("C27").Select
    Sheets("GLORY INYANG").Select
    Range("B25:E25").Select
    Range("C25:E25").Select
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(109,R[-18]C:R[-1]C)"
    Sheets("ELIZABETH GABRIEL").Select
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(109,R[-11]C:R[-1]C)"
    Sheets("ABASIOFON MONDAY").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-87
    Range("ABASIOFON_MONDAY[[DATE]:[CREDIT (Payment)]]").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Rows("18:1286").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("C18:E18").Select
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(109,R[-11]C:R[-1]C)"
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-87
End Sub`
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the basic code:

```vb
Public Sub clearAllTables()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lo As ListObject    'ListObject = Table
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each lo In ws.ListObjects
        lo.DataBodyRange.Delete
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

It will delete the rows from the table - but keeps header- and totals-row

Comment: Thanks @Ike This was a great guide. I actually had to do some modification to allow for more specifics.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of tweaks, I have been able to get to this point. But I am currently trying to make sure that these tables titled 'Glance' and 'Compiled_Ledger' do not get formatted with borders and colour as the rest of the tables.  This is how far I have gone.

```
Sub Total_Clear()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        For Each tbl In ws.ListObjects
            tbl.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
            With Selection.Interior
                .Pattern = xlNone
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
            On Error Resume Next
            If ws.Name <> "Glance" And ws.Name <> "Compiled_Ledger" Then
                With tbl.DataBodyRange
                    .Offset(2).Rows.Clear
                    .Offset(2).Resize(.Rows.Count - 60, .Columns.Count).Rows.Delete
                    .Rows(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
                End With
                On Error Resume Next
                If ws.Name <> "Glance" And ws.Name <> "Compiled_Ledger" Then
                    Range("A7:E8").Select
                    With Selection.Interior
                        .Pattern = xlSolid
                        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
                        .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
                        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                    End With
                End If
                Range("E8").Select
                Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("E8:E66")
                Range("E9:E66").Select
                With Selection.Interior
                    .Pattern = xlNone
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                End With
                Range("A7:E66").Select
                Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
                Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
                With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .ColorIndex = 0
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .Weight = xlThin
                End With
                With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .ColorIndex = 0
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .Weight = xlThin
                End With
                With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .ColorIndex = 0
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .Weight = xlThin
                End With
                With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .ColorIndex = 0
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .Weight = xlThin
                End With
                With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .ColorIndex = 0
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .Weight = xlThin
                End With
                With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .ColorIndex = 0
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .Weight = xlThin
                End With
                Range("C67:D67").Select
                Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(109,R[-60]C:R[-1]C)"
                Selection.Style = "Comma"
                Selection.Font.Size = 14
                With Selection.Font
                    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                End With
                Range("E67").Select
                Selection.Font.Size = 14
                With Selection.Font
                    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                End With
            End If
            On Error Resume Next
                ws.Activate
                ActiveSheet.Range("A9").Select
                ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = Selection.Row
                ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = Selection.Column
        Next tbl
    Next ws
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Glance").Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Any options or help with this?